# Is it safe to use admin-ajax.php in the frontend?

Tags: plugins, ajax, security

I am using [Filter Custom Fields & Taxonomies Light](https://wordpress.org/plugins/filter-custom-fields-taxonomies-light/). I found out it is using `admin-ajax.php` in the frontend for the AJAX search even not logged in.

See:

https://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/filter-custom-fields-taxonomies-light/trunk/profi-search-filter.php

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'sf_head', 1 );
function sf_head(){
    $settings = get_option( 'search-filter-settings' );
    if( !isset( $settings['style'] ) || $settings['style'] == '' )
        wp_register_style( 'sf-style', SF_URL . 'res/style.css' );
    else
        wp_register_style( 'sf-style', SF_URL . 'res/' . $settings['style'] . '.css');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'sf-style' ); 


    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-slider');
    wp_register_script( 'sf-script', SF_URL . 'res/sf.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'sf-script' );

    ?>
    <script>var sf_ajax_root = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>'</script>
    <?php
}
```

Is that a common way of doing AJAX in Wordpress or a security hole?

Comment: See [AJAX in Plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [documentation here](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins#Ajax_on_the_Viewer-Facing_Side) but don't miss the note 2 and the following points :

- AJAX on the front-end is more complicated, ajaxurl is not defined so 
  you have to call it with [wp_localize_script()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/).
- you have to use wp_ajax_nopriv_{action} for non logged in users
- there could be security issue !!!

**About the third point** :

Be careful because you give access to non logged in users to some data and functions. So you need to ask yourself about what you want to do. It could seem a little bit too much but to me when using AJAX on the front-end of WP you should make $_GET things, only for reading, for example infinite scroll ans stuffs like that, not delete, create and update actions.

Comment: I agree for the $_GET in fact when I use $_GET in ajax I use it as `(int)filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'post_id');` where (int) is sometimes (string).

Comment: @JMau What if you have for example audio player and you want to count plays, you have to use ajax on frontend to tell backend to update and retrieve play count in wpdb. Is there alternative to this?